# How to find $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{x}{5})^x$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> How to find $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^x\quad ?$$

I believe the answer is infinity, but I am trying the work bringing in natural logs and using L'Hopital's rule and I am missing something.

Comment: the Limit is $\infty$

Comment: I am trying to show the work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\frac x5 > 2 \implies \left(\frac{x}5\right)^x>2^x 
$$ and the latter tends to $\infty$.

Comment: I follow this just fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If $x\geq 5$ then
$$ \Big(\frac{x}{5}\Big)^x\geq \Big(\frac{x}{5}\Big)^5$$
hence
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(\frac{x}{5}\Big)^x\geq \lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(\frac{x}{5}\Big)^5=\infty$$

Comment: Why keep the exponent and not just $\big(\frac x5\big)^x\ge \frac x5\to\infty$ ?

Comment: Why not keep the exponent?

Comment: It seems to me that for $a>1$ the justification that $a^x>a^5$ and $a^x>a$ is exactly the same ($a^x$ is $\nearrow$), so I would just go for the simplest which is $a$. I'm just intrigued. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can write the limit as

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x(\ln x-\ln 5)}
$$
and note that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x(\ln x-\ln 5)=+\infty$$

Comment: that is what I tried, but don't you have to do L'Hopitals rule then?

Comment: @DavidHouse, no. Because the expression in the exponent tends to infinity, e^+infinity is infinity. Emilio, was that supposed to be implied? I think it may be good to be explicit because the $x(\ln x-\ln5) \to \infty$ so does $\exp(x(\ln x-\ln5))$.

Comment: Gotcha!  I was thinking that e^infinity * infinity was an indeterminate form.

Comment: Yes. I suppose that it's well known that $e^\infty=\infty$

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that for any $M\in \mathbb{R_+}$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{R_+}$ such that

$$x>N \implies f(x)>M.$$

Let $N=\max \{5M,5\}$

$$x>N \implies f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^x>\frac{x}{5} \geq M.$$